# Using arrays in a shell script

Tags: arrays, shell

I am trying to initialise an array in a shell script like below

```
declare -a testArr=( 'A' 'B' )
```

Also like below

```
testArr=( 'A' 'B' )
```

But in both the cases, I get the following error

```
shell1.sh: 1: shell1.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Can someone please tell me the reason for the above error?

Comment: Very likely your shebang is `#!/bin/sh` and not `#!/bin/bash`. Arrays are not supported in POSIX shells, but they are in Bash.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Ya sorry it is not bash. How can i use arrays in POSIX shells?

Comment: you can't. `sh` doesn't support arrays. If you need arrays, switch to Bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to use POSIX shell and POSIX shell does not support arrays, you can "emulate" array in this way:

```
set -- 'A' 'B'
```

Then you will have the only "array" available in POSIX shell ("$@") that contains A ($1) and B ($2).

And you can pass this array to another function, such as:

```
test() {
    echo "$2"
}

set -- 'A' 'B C'
test "$@"
```

If you need to save the array you can use the following function:

```
arrsave() {
    local i
    for i; do
        printf %s\\n "$i" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;1s/^/'/;\$s/\$/' \\\\/"
    done
    echo " "
}
```

And use it in the following way:

```
set -- 'A' 'B C'

# Save the array
arr=$(arrsave "$@")

# Restore the array
eval "set -- $arr"
```